# Qt - changing rotation center of QGraphicsRectItem

Tags: c++, qt

I made this code to rotate a `bullet` to an `enemy`:

```
void Bullet::turnToFutureLocation(Enemy *enemy)
{
    QLineF ln(mapToScene(rect().topLeft()), enemy->mapToScene(enemy->rect().topLeft()));
    setRotation(ln.angle());
}
```

both `bullet` and `enemy` derive from `QGraphicsRectItem`.
When I run my code my bullet isn't on the screen.
When I try to rotate it with given parameters this happens:

```
setRotation(0);
```

[image: Graphical Representation]

```
setRotation(10);
```

[image]
Instead of just rotating, the `bullet` rotates around the origin of the scene.
How can I get it to just rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `setTransformOriginPoint()` changes the center of the rotation.
The default center is always 0,0.

source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation